# Probability random function in $O(n^a)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics

Let $\{X(n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with values in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. We could view this as a random function $X\colon \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Since I do not have much knowledge about this field, I have some basic questions:

- Is it possible to compute (or give bounds) the probability that this sequence $\{X(n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$ viewed as a function is in $O(n^a)$ for $a$ in some range, say, $[2,3]$?

Comment: Each RV, $X_n$ has a CDF, $F_{X_n}(x)=P(X_n \leq x)$. If the RVs are IIDRV then it is one common $F$. So, what do you mean by a distribution on the set of all functions from the non-negative integers to the non-negative half line?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Some thinking made me realize that the first question does not make much sense... Does my second question make sense?

Comment: and the $X_n$'s are not identically distributed, but they are independent.

Comment: you indeed may be able to prove $X_n \in O(n^a)$ as $n\to \infty$ a.s. for specific random variables but I am not sure about general theorems regarding this task. Maybe someone else will stop by with more to say...